# Really strange error when implementing Samsung's fingerprint API: "Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null"

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, int, fingerprint

My app allows the user to use their fingerprint to access their pictures. This is the basic method to create the default dialog:

```
SpassFingerprint.IdentifyListener identifyListener = new SpassFingerprint.IdentifyListener() {
 @Override
 public void onFinished(int i) {
     if (i == SpassFingerprint.STATUS_AUTHENTIFICATION_SUCCESS || i == SpassFingerprint.STATUS_AUTHENTIFICATION_PASSWORD_SUCCESS) {
    MainActivity.myFolder.edit().putBoolean("samsung", (boolean) newValue).apply();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Fingerprint confirmed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else MainActivity.myFolder.edit().putBoolean("samsung", false).apply();
}

@Override
public void onReady() {

}

@Override
public void onStarted() {

}
};    
mSpassFingerprint.startIdentifyWithDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), identifyListener, true);
```

This works without error on my phone while I'm testing it, but in production mode it throws a NullPointerException that says "Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null". I have never seen an error like this ever. It has to be something with Samsung's method of authenticating the user or creating the dialog. Has anyone else ever seen something like this when using Samsung's fingerprint authentication?

Comment: Please include a full stack trace. Also, try to determine if the exception is happening in your code or in Samsung's (wouldn't be the first time, trust me).

Comment: @Karakuri I figured it out. It was something in proguard. Such a subtle mistake

Comment: Also, refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083338/expected-to-unbox-a-string-primitive-type-but-was-returned-null

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this question, it occurs because of `Proguard` with obfuscation is turned on. The fix is to add these line to your `proguard-rules` file:

```
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-keep class com.samsung.** {*;}
```