# Expected to unbox a 'String' primitive type but was returned null

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to use Java Reflection to call a method which takes a callback as an argument.  I instantiate all of the objects with Java Reflection.  Also, I am using a [Java Dynamic Proxy Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) as the callback argument.

I'm a couple of strange behaviors:

1. `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance()` method returns null
2. The following kinds of errors, depending on different versions I've tried of my code below:

   1. `Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null`
   2. `Expected to unbox a 'String' primitive type but was returned null`

Here is the interface I want to instantiate as an anonymous object as a Java Dynamic Proxy Class:

```
public interface MyListener {
    void onEvent(String eventName);
}
```

And here is how I instantiate the interface via `newProxyInstance()`:

```
Object callbackObject = null;

try {
    Class callbackClass = Class.forName("com.example.MyListener");

    Class[] interfaceArray = new Class[]{callbackClass};

    InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (method.getName().equals("onMyEvent")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "InvocationHandler.invoke onMyEvent");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    callbackObject = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            interfaceArray,
            invocationHandler);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, "newProxyInstance got exception [" + t + "] caused by [" + t.getCause() + "]");
}

Log.d(TAG, "callbackObject=[" + callbackObject + "]");

if (null == callbackObject) {
    Log.e(TAG, "callbackObject is null according to null check");
}
else {
    Log.d(TAG, "callbackObject is NOT null according to null check");
}
```

The log messages seem to conflict about whether callbackObject is null:

```
callbackObject=[null]
callbackObject is NOT null according to null check
```

According to [Why does newInstance() return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594804/why-does-newinstance-return-null) it's not possible for `newProxyInstance()` to return null because it gets the value from `newInstance()`.

So how can the result of `newProxyInstance()` be `null` and not `null`?  And what do these error messages like `Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution: `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance()` method returns null**

I figured out the Object returned by `newProxyInstance()` is *not* `null`, it merely appears to be `null`.  The log message that prints out the return value says it's null because Java implicitly calls `toString()` on the object.  But since the object is a `Proxy`, it gets forwarded to my `InvocationHandler`.  The real problem is with my `InvocationHandler` which always returns `null`.  I thought `null` was suitable because the `onEvent()` method returns `void`.  However, I didn't anticipate that `toString()` would also be forwarded to the `InvocationHandler`.

**Solution: `Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null`**

While trying to debug the apparent `null`, I ended up trying to call other methods on the object returned by `newProxyInstance()`, for example `hashcode()` and `getClass()`.  *All* of these methods get forwarded to the `InvocationHandler` which wasn't expecting them and so it just returned `null` for everything.  Since `null` is not a valid `int`, the `hashcode()` function resulted in the error `Expected to unbox a 'int' primitive type but was returned null`.

I was able to eliminate this error by making my `InvocationHandler` a little more robust:

```
    InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (method.getName().equals("onMyEvent")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "InvocationHandler.invoke onMyEvent");
                return null;
            }
            else if (String.class == method.getReturnType()) {
                return "";
            }
            else if (Integer.class == method.getReturnType()) {
                return Integer.valueOf(0);
            }
            else if (int.class == method.getReturnType()) {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (Boolean.class == method.getReturnType()) {
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
            else if (boolean.class == method.getReturnType()) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
```

However, the actual solution for me was just to remove the debugging code that called `hashcode()`, etc. and trust that the `newProxyInstance()` result was not `null`.  And in the future, keep in mind that the `InvocationHandler` gets forwarded all method calls.

Thanks to [artaxerxe's solution for Proxy object throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002113/2848676) for giving me the insight.